# undefined inside javascript loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to output a list of all my products that I have in firebase database,for that I go through this loop:

```
db.collection("products").get().then((querySnapshot) => {

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
   var myHTML = '<h6 id="name">' + doc.name +' </h6>';

    wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML

        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

However in my html is prints **undefined**. Can someone point out the problem and how can I solve it?
P.S I am new in web

Comment: are you getting response in querySnapshot?

Comment: the doc.data() returns an array. that works fine @dharmaraj

Comment: One thing, here your are replacing element with id:wrapper on every element of an array, this will change content of element and atlast only last value will be visible to end user on html

Comment: And, replace data.name by doc.data().name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name property exists in the `DocumentData` and not in the `DocumentSnapshot` itself. Try this:

```
// no data in original code
// var myHTML = '<h6 id="name">' + doc.name +' </h6>';


var myHTML = '<h6 id="name">' + doc.data().name +' </h6>';
// add data()                       ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
db.collection("products").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    
    let customHtml = ``;
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        customHtml += '<h6 id="name">' + doc.name +' </h6>';
    });
    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = customHtml;
});
```